# XCode, fix always true warning in this check valid png code

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-warnings

In `XCode5`, i have this code

```
1  - (BOOL)checkValidPNGImage{

2        NSData *imagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.imageFullPath];
3        if ([imagedata length] < 4)
4            return NO;    
5         const char * bytes = (const char *)[imagedata bytes];    
6         if (bytes[0] != 0x89 || bytes[1] != 0x50)
7             return NO;
8         if (bytes[[imagedata length] - 2] != 0x60 ||
9             bytes[[imagedata length] - 1] != 0x82)
10            return NO;
11    return YES;
12 }
```

in line 6 and line 8 it get warning

```
Comparison of constant 137 with expression of type 'const char' is always true
```

and

```
Comparison of constant 130 with expression of type 'const char' is always true
```

how to fix this? btw i got the code above from somewhere i forgot, so i open for any other alternative to check valid png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824357/png-validation-on-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

char is from -128 to 127. So it can't exceed 0x7f.

-

Use unsigned char instead

Comment: so, i have to change char into what?, is it save to change it to Byte?

Comment: @DeckyFx Using unsigned char instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead of `const char * bytes = (const char *)[imagedata bytes];`

```
const unsigned char * bytes = (const unsigned char *)[imagedata bytes];
```